# Popper.js React Wrapper - React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, popper.js, react-popper

I am trying to implement the [standalone example from here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-popper-example?file=standalone.js), using `react-popper` - I basically just copy pasted the code for now. It does render the component. However, when I click everything breaks. I am using it in Gatsby.js - if that should make a difference?

That's the error(s) I'm getting:

> index.js:2177 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at StandaloneExample.js:36.

And:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...)(...) is not a function
>       at InnerPopper.render (Popper.js:159)

And:

> The above error occurred in the  component:
>       in InnerPopper (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in Popper (at StandaloneExample.js:34)

And multiple of these:

> TypeError: Object(...)(...) is not a function

Here's my code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { Popper, Arrow } from 'react-popper'
import './popper.css'

class StandaloneExample extends PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
    }
  }


  handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Standalone Popper Example</h2>
        <div
          ref={div => (this.target = div)}
          style={{ width: 120, height: 120, background: '#b4da55' }}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          Click {this.state.isOpen ? 'to hide' : 'to show'} popper
        </div>
        {this.state.isOpen && (
          <Popper className="popper" target={this.target}>
            Popper Content for Standalone example
            <Arrow className="popper__arrow" />
          </Popper>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default StandaloneExample
```

I've modified things a bit (the way I implement state etc.), because I thought this might fix the errors I'm getting, but it didn't. Apart from that the code is pretty much the same as in the sandbox example - I'm not sure where it breaks.

edit: I am importing things like so:

```
import StandaloneExample from './MenuDropdown/StandaloneExample.js'
```

and am using it in my render function like so:

```
<StandaloneExample />
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.target` ?

Comment: The example you linked is for `react-popper@0.x`. Check you aren't with version 1 or greater.

Comment: @samb102 - that was it, thank you. Installed exact versions and the error is gone. If you submit this as an answer I'll pick it, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you linked is for `react-popper@0.x`.

Please check that you aren't with version 1 or greater.

`react-popper` V1 had breaking changes from V0.

You can find V1 doc [here](https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-popper) and V0 doc [here](https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-popper/tree/v0.x).